# angularjs expression if else condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<p>{{isExisted}}</p>
```

I want to display "Active" or "Inactive" but the isExisted returned true or false. How to do if else conditional and change it to new value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) can be used.

```
<p>{{isExisted ? "Active" : "InActive"}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

another version is that it does in controller through function:

```
$scope.getStatusText = function(){
  return isExisted ? "Active" : "InActive";
}
```

then

```
<p>{{getStatusText()}}</p>
```